# Exclude Parent categories from product collection

Tags: magento-1.8, category

Hi i have below categories,

```
Category 1 (id 1)
   - Sub category 1 (id 11)
   - Sub Category 2 (id 12)

Category 2 (id 2)
   - Sub Category 3 (id 13)
   - Sub category 4 (id 14)
```

And all my products are assigned to One Parent and one child category.

If i use

```
    foreach ($this->getItemCollection()->getItems() as $item) {
        print_r($item->getCategoryIds());
        ...............
}
```

Below is my result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 11
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 12
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 13
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 14
)
```

Now how can i `exclude product's parent category id's`, `this case how to remove categories having id's 1 and 2`

Comment: Not the best idea, have a look on my answer, but to not delete it... what about array_shift($item->getCategoryIds())

Comment: My question here would be do you need the products attached to the parent categories?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way. First find number of categories ie

```
$item_length = count($item->getCategoryIds());
```

Next, instead of using foreach loop for categoryIds use for loop

This should look like

```
for($i=1; $i<$item_length; $i++){
     print($item->getCategoryIds[i]);
}
```

Frankly speaking i haven't tried this code yet. Please try and put your comments below whether it works or not. Meanwhile i'll try it myself too

Comment: How could this will exclude parent category ?

Comment: In  your listing the first category you are getting is the parent category. Skipping the first value will naturally skip the first ie parent category

Comment: thats right, but it's not for all cases, on some cases products don't have parent category !

Comment: There is another way to do this then. If you are only concerned about the child category of certain category, you can try using this code `$_categories=$this->getCurrentChildCategories(); ` this will get all the child category of the current category.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the category collection and then filter by `being parent`

```
$product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('children_count', 0);
```